# 2 rectangles in square

Tags: geometry

1. Area of black square is 1x1.
2. Blue rectangles are identical, with area of 1xA.

---

**Find A**

I really don't see it ..

[image: 2 rectangles in a square]

Comment: As a first approach, you have four black right-angled triangles in that drawing. Can you say anything about those? What are their sides? Are they related in any way?

Comment: Well yea, they are identical in pairs, but that leads me nowhere ..

Comment: What are their hypothenuses? And can you write down any arithmetical relation between their legs? Also, note that they are similar.

Comment: Ooh, I see answer when they are similar, but can't see why .. ?

Comment: Look at their angles, and keep in mind that the blue rectangles are, well, rect-angles (i.e. they have right-angled corners)

Comment: Thanks, I get it now ..

Comment: Can you please tell me final result, I'm having trouble with simplifying the relations .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Given: $AD=GH=1$ and $DF=GJ=A$. We label the segments:
$$EG=CK=x\\
EH=JC=y\\
GF=BK=w\\
FJ=BH=z$$

Then by the Pythagorean theorem, we have the following system of equations:
$$x^2+y^2=1\\
w^2+z^2=A^2$$
Additionally, we have:
$$A+y+z=1\\
w+x=1$$
The total area of the square is $1$, then the last equation is:
$$2A+wz+xy=1$$
This gives two possible solutions:
$$\left\{A\to \frac{1}{2},w\to 0,z\to \frac{1}{2},x\to 1,y\to 0\right\}\\
\left\{A\to 2-\sqrt{3},w\to 1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},z\to \sqrt{3}-\frac{3}{2},x\to \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},y\to \frac{1}{2}\right\}$$

Comment: Yeah, I got that too, but it doesn't work ...
Answer is password for rar file, it won't open .. I guess the password is wrong ..